# how to check if the client has closed the connection in websocket POCO C++

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

The requirement i have is i do not want to send close frame to client if the websocket is already closed by client.

So i want to know if the websocket is still alive. How to? No API's on POCO using 1.6 version with C++